# calculated values in ISERIES sequel query result in decimal data errors or a value of zero

Tags: ibm-midrange, division, multiplication, db2-400

I am wondering why the following SEQUEL calculations do not work properly and they seem to be based more on content than on syntax. This all started when one of our Viewpoint (Help Systems) sequel queries failed to calculate properly on one row of data (not all rows) for one column. I copied the code from the Sequel Viewpoint application  and paste directly into a `STRSQL` on the iseries and experienced the same results. You will see below calculations using the value 922.459 – one resulting in `++++`, one resulting in correct value (without parenthesis) and one with correct calculation but calculations slimmed down. You also see value of 50 – where the result is zero and one using 50.5 showing correct result. I am getting data decimal errors but of course nothing to help me understand why – especially since I am working with all hard-coded numbers. One thing I did find – if I change the number from 50 to 50.0 – the calculation is correct.  However if I do the same for number 922 – both 922 and 922.0 result in the `+++`. Any ideas?

```
SELECT  Bprod,(1.1*1/1)*(922.459*1/1000)*1.06 
FROM    BOMBYITEM
```

yields:

```
Item                                               Numeric Expression   
Number                                                                  
124927                               +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

while:

```
SELECT   bprod,1.1*1/1 * 922.459*1/1000 *1.06 
FROM     BOMBYITEM
```

yields:

```
Item                                                 Numeric Expression   
Number                                                                    
124927                                       1.075587194000000000000000
```

and:

```
SELECT  bprod,(1.1)*(.922459) *1.06   
FROM    BOMBYITEM
```

yields:

```
Item                                 Numeric Expression 
Number                                                  
124927                                   1.075587194
```

and:

```
SELECT  Bprod,(1.1*1/1)*(50*1/1000)*1.06   
FROM    BOMBYITEM
```

yields:

```
Item                                                  Numeric Expression 
Number                                                                   
124927                                            .000000000000000000000
```

and:

```
SELECT  Bprod,(1.1*1/1)*(50.5*1/1000)*1.06 
FROM    BOMBYITEM
```

yields:

```
Item                                               Numeric Expression    
Number                                                                   
124927                               .0588830000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: I hope the constants shown in your expressions are merely sample values for database columns in another query you are working on.

Answer (score 3):

What you call "based more on content than on syntax" is a common property of operations in many computing environments, not just in DB2 SQL. What's happening is that the evaluation engine, in the absence of explicit type information, is inferring the type from the way the value is expressed.

The easiest to understand example is all-integer arithmetic. The difference between `50` and `50.0` is that the implicit *type* of `50` is integer, whereas the implicit *type* of `50.0` is some kind of decimal or float. When both operands are integers, some evaluation engines do integer arithmetic only, and produce an integer result. So `9/3` is evaluated to `3`, but so are `10/3` and `11/3`. `12/3` is evaluated to `4`. `1/3` and `2/3` are both evaluated to `0`. So this explains the example where your result is 0. `(50*1/1000)` involves only integers and thus evaluates to `0`, making the whole expression evaluate to 0.

Now, decimal and floating-point arithmetic are harder to reason about, because there are many ways to represent these numbers, and the rules for their precision are often very arcane. Databases especially are prone to having both base-10 fixed-precision decimals as well as IEEE floating point, which are completely different systems, neither of which can accurately represent a mathematical quantity as simple to humans as one third.

In DB2 SQL's case, your values are fixed-precision decimals, and once the limits of the precision are exceeded, the results blow up. Unfortunately, I can't explain *exactly* why your values are beyond the limits of precision, because I don't understand the rules myself. (I try not to do a lot of arithmetic in SQL!) You might want to try reading here:

[Rules for result data types](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzopcomb.htm)

While JamesA's example doesn't help you directly, you can still benefit from his advice if you judiciously apply explicit precision specifications to *components* of your expression, to influence the precision of intermediate results. For example:

```
SELECT (1.1) * (922.459/1000) * 1.06 FROM BOMBYITEM
```

doesn't work, but this does:

```
SELECT (1.1) * DEC(922.459/1000, 31, 15) * 1.06 FROM BOMBYITEM
```

Note that your parentheses are forcing certain unfavorable order of operations.  My nonworking example can be made to work by removing the parentheses:

```
SELECT 1.1 * 922.459/1000 * 1.06 FROM BOMBYITEM
```

It also works if I use a decimal or float instead of an integer:

```
SELECT (1.1) * (922.459/1000.0) * 1.06 FROM BOMBYITEM
```

Unless you know what you're doing, I recommend (1) using parentheses only where logically necessary, and (2) avoiding integers in calculations that ultimately produce decimal or floating results. These will probably give the evaluation engine its best chance of being able to finish the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on the info from [the IBM InfoCenter for iSeries 7.1, SQL expressions with Arithmetic operators](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzwarithop.htm) and the "Decimal Arithmetic in SQL" page underneath that.

All numbers in SQL have a precision (total number of digits) and a scale (number of decimal places).  You can declare the precision and scale directly when you define a variable or a column with something like `Declare My_Number as Decimal(11,6)` (a number up to 99,999.999999: 11 digits, 6 of which are after the decimal point).  SQL defaults to a maximum precision and scale of 31.  (You can raise the maximum to 63 by an explicit declaration.)

When you perform calculations, SQL attempts to do the mathematical operation without loss of calculation accuracy if at all possible.  In the case of addition, subtraction, and/or multiplication, this is a fairly straightforward modification of the result's precision and scale.

With division, however, SQL basically throws as much scale as possible at the result.

So when you specify an operation like (1.1*1/1), SQL interprets that as:

> 1.1 * 1 = multiply a decimal(5,1) by an int; the int is promoted to a decimal(5,0) and the result is a decimal(10,1).  (Larger integer values would be promoted to a decimal(11, 0) or a decimal(19,0).) *(Note, I'm not actually sure what precision gets assigned to a literal value; couldn't find that in the docs.  But since you specified 1 decimal place, the scale will definitely be 1.)*
>
> (decimal(10,1) / 1) = divide a decimal(10,1) by an int:  Int is promoted to a (decimal(5,0)) for the process.  This results in a decimal(31,21) or thereabouts.

When you get to 50 / 1000, that is integer division, and as such produces an integer, which clearly equals 0.  Change it to 50.0 / 1000, and you get the same basic process as the previous calculation, producing another decimal(10,21).

Then you multiply again:

> decimal(31,21) * decimal(31,21) = decimal(63,31)  *(intermediate result)*
>
> decimal(63,31) * decimal(5,2) = decimal(63,31) *(final result)*

and you end up with the final result showing 31 decimal places.

For your initial operation that produces the +++++++ result, the answer is probably being calculated correctly but you're ending up with a very wide-formatted number like a decimal(63,31), and that's too wide for the display; whereas with the version that DOES produce results, since you're not forcing the order of operations with parentheses, one or more of the intermediate results is dropping enough precision and/or scale that the final result is now short enough to be displayed properly.

Comment: Didn't know if you were specifically trying to maintain a rep that was appropriate for your name, but this answer is a nice walk-through of what I was trying to express, except you've included a lot of concrete details. (Could you feel the breeze from my hand-waving?)

Comment: @JohnY, I did kinda like having that particular amount, but I'll get over the additional rep somehow.  ;-)

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure I got some of the concrete details wrong anyway, but hopefully it still gives a decent idea of what's going on under the covers.

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly define your expected precision and scale using [ROUND](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscaround.htm) and/or [DECIMAL](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscadec.htm) when performing decimal calculations.

```
SELECT Bprod, ROUND((1.1*1/1)*(922.459*1/1000)*1.06, 2) FROM BOMBYITEM
```

Comment: I guess the upvote is for the generally good advice, but this answer doesn't address the question at all.  Try this statement (with appropriate table and column names for your system) and you'll see it doesn't work. (The result is the same as OP describes.)